# Machine Learning: Cross-validation score

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

In scikit-learn example [Model selection: choosing estimators and their parameters](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html)

[image]

Why we leave 2 trials to test, but we can receive 0.93489148580968284 score? I guess we only have 0, 50 or 100%.

Comment: I don't know Python, but it looks like you are doin 3-fold CV, so partitioning your data into 3 parts, in which case you are using 1 partition to test your set (not 2). So unless your sample size is 3, this partition should have more than 1 sample.

Comment: There are different ways to score models. The scoring that gives you 1 if the model predicts correctly and 0 if the model predicts incorrectly is called "accuracy" (and it can't be used in regression problems). However, accuracy is a highly problematic score and so, by default, its using a score that measures how likely (the probability) the model thought the correct answer was. That's why you can get scores other an 0, 0.5, and 1.

Answer (score 1):

The examples don't have the same dataset (`X` vs. `X_digits`).  The first code snippet is just to demonstrate how the splitter works, and the latter to show usage.

Otherwise, you would be correct: as @Johnny points out, SVC's default scorer is accuracy, and as you point out, that would be limited to one of 0, 0.5, or 1 on the small test sets.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the second code snippet doesn't correspond to the first code snippet. It would appear that the test sample had only two trials of letters if you look at the first snippet, but the second snippet is actually from a different dataset with digits instead of letters. The digits dataset is larger.

Answer (score 0):

Score is a measure in sklearn to evaluate prediction models. Each prediction model in sklean implements the score method. Different models may have different ways (different scores) to evaluate itself. You can read this post [[Python/Sklearn] How does .score() works?](https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/27261)

Comment: Thank you very much. I just simply think accuracy = y_true/y_pred, so when you have only 2 samples to test. All possibility that you can have include: 0/2, 1/2 and 2/2.

Comment: You can find what the score returns from the document of sklearn. SVC score:http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.score